# Create user with shell access but no GUI login

Tags: shell, gui

I need to create a User that can interact with shell it has home directory but no GUI login. I have looked at many articles on this. but I am pretty confused as the correct process `useradd --system user_name`  this will not allow user shell access and I believe I have to modify a file to allow user access to shell.

I have to install Magento on ubuntu. this user needs to own files and folders and be part of www-data group as well as access to CLI to execute commands.

Comment: Tonysar I've copied your comment to the question so it can be easily found and read by people trying to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I'm puzzled why you're trying to add a system account `(--system`). Just use `useradd` or `adduser` according to the documentation (`man useradd` and `man adduser`):

```
# Create user "fred" with sensible defaults
 adduser fred
```

Or if you don't have `adduser`, the lower-level alternative:

```
# Create user "fred" with useful overrides
useradd --create-home --shell /bin/bash fred
```